# Не работает запрос INSERT INTO mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert

INSERT ничего не добавляет в БД при использовании в VALUES переменных, как только я уже не пробовал записывать, не понимаю как всё таки нужно. Но работает если написать обычный текст в кавычках.

```html
<form action="index.php" metchod="GET">
  <div class="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="textarea">
    <textarea id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Ваш отзыв" name="textarea"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" name="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
if ($_GET['name'] == '') { 
    echo 'Введите имя';
} elseif ($_GET['textarea'] == '') {
    echo 'Напишите отзыв';
} else { 

    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $date = date('d.m.Y', time());
    $time = date('H.i.s', time());
    $review = $_GET['textarea'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `FirstP` (`name`, `date`, `time`, `rev`) VALUES 
             ('".$name."', '".$date."', '".$time."', '".$review."')"; 
    executeQuery($query);
} 
}

function executeQuery($query) {
$db = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
mysqli_close($db);
return $result;
}
```

Comment: Никогда не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса. С ними вечно куча проблем возникает. Используйте подготавливаемые запросы и привязку переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: P.S. Не стоит хранить дату и время в отдельных полях, да еще и как я подозреваю текстом. Вы их даже сравнивать не сможете, не говоря уже о таких часто встречающихся вещах, как "найти все за последнюю неделю". Сделайте одно поле типа datetime. с ним гораздо легче работать. текущую дату даже из php формировать не придется `insert into Tab(name, date, rev) values(?, now(), ?)` функция now() это встроенная функция MySQL возвращающая текущую дату-время.

Comment: Так же после выполнения запроса проверяйте на ошибки и выводите их, что бы всегда знать что именно идет не так. без текста ошибки, который возвращает БД можно сутки пытаться понять что не так в запросе

Comment: оффтоп: я правильно понимаю, что у Вас функция устанавливает соединение, исполняет запрос а затем... **закрывает** его?! вообще mysqli_close не нужно использовать, если, конечно, Вы не собираетесь исполнять php-скрипт в течение длительного времени (тут уж определите для себя сами, что такое "длительно"). Ходят легенды, что бОльшая часть времени уходит именно на установление соединения, чем на исполнение коротенького запроса.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский Это не легенды.

Comment: @Mike подготавливаемые запросы и привязка действительно помогли, спасибо.